# Maven multi-project child can't have same version

Tags: maven

I have this maven multi-project configuration with a parent project and three child projects:

Parent POM:

```
<...>
<groupId>my.proj</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
```

Children POM:

```
<parent>
 <groupId>my.proj</groupId>
 <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
 <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
<groupId>my.proj.web</groupId>
<artifactId>web</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
```

If I set the children version to 1.0, I get a warning:

```
version is duplicate of parent version
```

But that is what I want, because my entire project is version 1.0, it looks natural to me. Why is this not allowed (or discouraged)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify the version, maven 3 will automatically use the same version as the parent project, you will only have to specify the version in the parent. So the warning is suggesting to remove this redundancy.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. So this was mandatory in maven2? I copied the snippet from a maven2 example and it was like that...

Comment: @EugenioCuevas: Yes, this is a new feature in maven 3. The same inheritance works for the `groupId`.

Answer (score 1):

Maven's POM inherits some stuff from its parent, including `vesion` but also `groupId` for example. So, in your case, it's enough to just set `artifactId`. What you see is warning that you duplicate some of these inherited declarations.